# Unread attributes when JAXB unmarshalling with XMLReader

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

So far, I've been unmarshalling XML with this code:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(clasz);
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
return (T) u.unmarshal(reader);
```

However, since I now need to set some security features (such as preventing the access of external DTDs, I'm doing it like this:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(clasz);
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
XMLReader xmlReader = spf.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();

// Parser feature switch
// spf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);

InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
SAXSource source = new SAXSource(xmlReader, inputSource);

Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
return (T) u.unmarshal(source);
```

Strangely though, the results are different. In the second case, none of my xml attributes are read. For instance,

```
<a with="MO2+IG4+IG5+XZ0" ned="N02">41560113</a>
```

corresponds to object A, but its attributes with and ned are empty with the second code, whereas the value is correctly read.

Any hints at what may cause this problem, or possible solutions would be greatly appreciated. (note that my xml is not using namespaces)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why was causing this issue, but I've solved it differently.

So, hoping this helps anyone:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(clasz);

XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_VALIDATING, validate);
xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, supportDTD);
xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, supportExternalEntities);
XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(xml));

Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
return (T) u.unmarshal(xsr);
```